# Is AWS DynamoDB is similar to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We are working on a project where we have chosen to one NO-SQL database. we come across DynamoDB. I want to know that DynamoDB and MongoDB both are the same or totally different in terms of features and API point of view. Which is the best choice DynamoDB or MongoDB?

Comment: They are totally different, with different feature set, different approach to solve the same problems, and different strength/weaknesses as well. There is no "best" choice. It's really a matter of which one can fulfil your needs.

Comment: @kevin, thanks for prompt response..